# group objects using stream collector

Tags: java, java-stream, collectors

I have list of objects, let's say of class Document:

```
class Document {

    private final String id;
    private final int length;

    public Document(String id, int length) {
        this.id = id;
        this.length = length;
    }

    public int getLength() {
        return length;
    }
}
```

Task at hand is to group them in Envelopes so that number of pages (Document.length) does not exceed certain number.

```
class Envelope {

    private final List<Document> documents = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

So for example, if I had follwing List of Documents:

```
Document doc0 = new Document("doc0", 2);
Document doc1 = new Document("doc1", 5);
Document doc2 = new Document("doc2", 5);
Document doc3 = new Document("doc3", 5);
```

and **max page count in envelope is let's say 7**, than I expect 3 envelopes with following documents:

```
Assert.assertEquals(3, envelopeList.size());

Assert.assertEquals(2, envelopeList.get(0).getDocuments().size()); // doc0, doc1
Assert.assertEquals(1, envelopeList.get(1).getDocuments().size()); // doc2
Assert.assertEquals(1, envelopeList.get(2).getDocuments().size()); // doc3
```

I have implemented this with traditional for loop and bunch of if's but question is, is it possible to do this more elegant way with streams and collectors?

thank you and best regards

Dalibor

Comment: can you the current code you have ?

Comment: yes, please: https://github.com/dkalna/DocumentSpliterator.git

Comment: It's better to share the code in the question instead of linking to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For batching the documents based on the length, we need to maintain the state of accumulated lengths. `Streams` are not the best choice when external state needs to be maintained and custom loop should be simpler and efficient option.

---

If we force fit, streams for this scenario, the `DocumentSpliterator` would change as below:

```
public static List<Couvert> splitDocuments(List<Document> docs) {

    IntUnaryOperator helper = new IntUnaryOperator() {
        private int bucketIndex = 0;
        private int accumulated = 0;

        public synchronized int applyAsInt(int length) {
            if (length + accumulated > MAX) {
                bucketIndex++;
                accumulated = 0;
            }
            accumulated += length;
            return bucketIndex;
        }
    };

    return new ArrayList<>(docs.stream()
                               .map(d -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(helper.applyAsInt(d.getLength()), d))
                               .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(AbstractMap.SimpleEntry::getKey,
                                       Collector.of(Couvert::new,
                                               (c, e) -> c.getDocuments().add(e.getValue()),
                                               (c1, c2) -> {c1.getDocuments().addAll(c2.getDocuments());return c1;})))
                               .values());
}
```

**Explanation:**

- `helper` maintains the accumulated length and provides a new bucket index when it exceeds max. I have used `IntUnaryOperator` interface here. Alternatively, we can use any interface that takes an `int` parame and returns an `int`.
- Regarding the stream,

  - `Document` is mapped to a `SimpleEntry` of bucketIndex and Document.
  - The stream of `SimpleEntry` is first grouped based on the bucketIndex. Another `Collector` transforms the stream of `Document` for a particuar bucketIndex to a `Couvert`. Output of the `collect()` is `Map<Integer,Couvert>`
- Finally, the `Collection` of `Couvert` are converted to a list and returned.

*Note:* For this implementation, I removed the `front` parameter and included it as part of the `docs` list.

Comment: Maintaining state in predicates, functions, etc, is considered **bad practice**, as it stops working i.e. when parallel streams are used. It also complicates debugging and adds complexity